# How to conver raw_input() from a text using int() in python

Tags: python, string, integer

i am learning to code in python. I am learning how to use numbers as string data from raw_input and convert these numbers to integers then use them to do number manipulations such as multiplications. Below my code is the error i am getting. Any light on this will be very welcomed. Thanks

`python`

```
num = raw_input("what is your favourite number?")
num= int(num) #convert num from text into a number using int() and double it.
print("Double my favourite number is ") +(num*2)
```

`python`
This is the error i am getting

`python`

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects on line 3 in main.py

`python`

Comment: `raw_input()` no longer exists. It was in Python 2.x, which is obsolete. You should be using `Python 3.x`, and this function is now called `input()`.

Comment: If you're just starting to learn Python, it would be a really good idea to skip Python 2 (`raw_input()` is just `input()` in Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing fine converting user input from a `str` to an `int`

Your only problem is that you're trying to add an `int` to the return value of `print()`:

```py
print("Double my favourite number is ") +(num*2)

# is the same as:
print("Double my favourite number is ")
None + (num * 2)  # because print() will return None
```

To solve this, a few options:

Fix the parenthesis for `print` to completely surround the `str` and the `int` and convert the `int` back into a `str` before "adding" (concatenating) to the `str`:

```py
print("Double my favourite number is " + str(num * 2))
```

You can also use interpolation via f-strings for the same/similar purpose, which will automatically call `str()` on interpolated values (the `num * 2`).

```py
print(f"Double my favourite number is {num * 2}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I found that it works using.. print("Double my favourite number is " + str(num * 2)) and using the f string gives me errors..it could be the website trinket.io not using python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can print using `,` instead of `+` to append values, also consider using [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/):

```
print("Double my favourite number is ", num*2)
```

Or:

```
print(f"Double my favourite number is {num*2}")
```